# How to find the data type of the retrieved column which is not from any table

Tags: database, sqldatatypes

I am using the following query to retrieve the Today's date in a formatted value (say 30 March, 2016). Can I find the data type (whether it is `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`) of the retrieved column Today?

Query is:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + convert(varchar(2),day(getdate())) + ', ' + convert(varchar(4),year(getdate())) Today
```

Give me query to find the data type of Today mentioned in the above query

Answer (score 0):

The below query will return the data type of any selected column

```
select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY((SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + convert(varchar(2),day(getdate())) + ', ' + convert(varchar(4),year(getdate())) Today WHERE 1=1),'BaseType')
```

The syntax is `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( expression , property )`

There are other properties such as

```
Precision                 

Scale

TotalBytes

Collation

MaxLength
```